# Need to Add new parameter to Working stored procedure in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

This SP is used in front end it has 7 parameters need to add one more parameter(as i have done) so that
**call proc_123(2018-01-10, 2022-10-07 ,-1,  1, 50,-1 ,-1,'airport');**

Comment: Welcome to [dba stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)  Can you please add more details to your question?

Comment: BUG:  Dates have to be quoted.  (They look like strings, but are stored as numbers.)  Meanwhile, I don't understand the question about adding a parameter.  Most changes require you to DROP and reCREATE the SP.